# Own QR code scanner app for android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I'm beginner in android and I need to create own QR code scanner app.

After searching for some library, of course I found zxing library (http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), but if I understand right, there must be installed BarcodeScanner application to use it and this library call this app. This variant is bad for me, because I need only my own app. 
But if I'm not right, how to use this library without installing BarcodeScanner?

Also I found this: http://www.blackdogfoundry.com/blog/zbar-bar-code-qr-code-reader-android/, and I'm not sure that it will work fine with all devices.

Did anyone do some qr readers, what did you use? Do you know some other good libraries for this, except of zxing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ZXing is good and useful library.  I think you are mixing up library itself and application
which is also produced by the project

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt be so quick to dismiss Barcode Scanner.

I recently used it in an App that needed to read barcodes. It works seamlessly with my App. The only downside is that it needs to be installed by the user, but to be honest weighting that up against the time and money it would take to develop a Barcode reader from scratch, its a no brainer. If the user does not have it installed it will not break your app.

I know this is not the answer you were looking for but just thought I would offer my experience

Answer (score 1):

You may also try to call the BarCode scanner App and obtain the result in the parameter of strings rather than importing the whole zxing library into your project due to substantial cost to code integration into your project . Using intents and overriding the OnActivityResult is already a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

XZing is your answer!
yeah yeah they try to push it to use as an external library, but that relies on the user having it installed.... but it's all open source and you can use it however you prefer.

So download that code, integrate it directly into your app and there you go.